# How do you make superhuman strength "make sense" in a fantasy setting?

Tags: creative-writing, fantasy, magic

I want to preface this by saying that I'm aware of how contradictory it sounds to apply real-world logic onto something that is inherently supernatural in a supernatural setting. Saying that, I like to believe that there is a sense of satisfaction that can be found in writing something supernatural that is as close to reality as it can be!

How does someone reason magic to work as a substitute for lack of physical ability or attain superhuman strength with magic? What is the magic supposed to affect: the cells of the character? The space around the character? A mix of both?

I know I'm just throwing out questions, but I have a hard time visualizing how to attain superhuman strength using magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *Mistborn*, one magic system allowed a character to store an attribute in the metal bands they wear, and then draw that attribute as needed. So, you might allow yourself to be weaker that normal as you sleep, or as you are having your morning breakfast, or whatever, and all the strength you 'save' goes into your metal bands. Then, when you need strength, the stored attribute floods back into your body. Health, memory, speed, etc were played with in this system.

You can design your own magic however you like. Your ideas are good ones. Perhaps the magic allows someone to multiply their mitochondria in a temporary burst. That immediately gives them more energy and stamina because of mitochondrial function. Others in this system might be able to multiply some other cellular component--a detox system or some such--to achieve remarkable health or what have you.

Or perhaps a new magic system allows the space around a character to change, yes, or gravity. The magic allows the character to create 'gravimetric bubbles' and appear strong when really they are manipulating fields.

Perhaps something at the subatomic level--playing with quarks in such a way that molecular cohesion is impacted?

I think the answer to your question is to look at the variety of magic systems already developed and brainstorm off of those.

Comment: I haven't thought about playing around with gravity, that's something I gotta take a look into! Thanks for your insight, SFWriter!